# Converting floating point number to Q-notation fixed point number in C/Java?

Tags: dsp-core, fixed-point

I am trying to convert from a floating point number to a Q-notation signed 16-bit fixed point number (e.g. Q15). How can this be done in C or Java? I searched online but could not find any available code.

Answer (score 3):

If your floating point number is X, then

X_Q15 = 32768 * X

if (X_Q15 > 32767)
    X_Q15 = 32767;

if (X_Q15 < -32768)
    X_Q15 = -32768;

Comment: You also have to round your result to the nearest integer after multiplication.

Comment: Note that in @james3849's example, X_Q15 should be wider than 16 bits so that the comparisons will work correctly. Only after it passes the overflow and underflow checks should you assign to a 16 bit variable.